# Add Data to Response of WP-JSON Root

Tags: wp-api, rest-api

The default content at /wp-json/ contains name, description, url etc. but I want to add some additional content at this root level.

I see lots of ways to modify the responses of items with object types but am missing how to modify the main index.

It appears I want to modify the $available array of the [get_index](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_server/get_index/) function of /wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php/ but I'm just not sure how to filter/hook that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterResponse($response){
  $data = $response->data;
  $data['extra_field'] = 'some data';
  $response->set_data($data);
  return $response;
 }

add_filter('rest_index', 'filterResponse');
```

[Thanks to Jeff](http://jeffreyeverhart.com)